# Hiding unused axis in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using two Y axes (right and left)
When I hide all the used datasets for one of them, the ticks (Axis labels) turn to 1 to -1.

I want to to hide the axis or the labels when it is not used, any ideas?

Before Hiding:
[Both Y Axes used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNH06.png)

After Hiding:
[Right Y-Axis Changed - Not used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRFt.png)

Options>Scales:

```
        yAxes: [
            {type: "linear", id: "y-axis-0", display: true, position: "right",gridLines:{display: false},
            scaleLabel:{display: true, labelString: 'mBar'}},
            {type: "linear", id: "y-axis-1", display: true, position: "left",ticks: {beginAtZero:true},
            scaleLabel:{display: true, labelString: 'Knots/°C'} }
          ]
```

Didn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
   If you want to remove the x axis and y axis data so to do that you need 
        to use scales and put in bar-chart-demo.ts file and inside export
          class you have to paste like that what  i mentioned below 
             and it worked . 

 public barChartOptions:any = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
     animation: false,
     scaledisplay:false,
     responsive: true,

scales: {
   xAxes: [
    {
        display: false
    }
  ],
   yAxes: [
      {
        display: false
    }
]
}


   };``
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mentioned how to use it now .

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the axis in your code. Just add an angular on-mouseover event and set the display to true/false with negation !condition:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [
        {
            display: false
        }
    ],
    yAxes: [
        {
            display: false
        }
    ]
}
```